# Partitions with subsets of limited cardinality

Tags: partitions

Is there a way to compute the number of partitions such that each set in the partition has a cardinality lower or equal to two? If yes, is there also an efficient algorithm to compute these partitions?

Answer (score 2):

For a set with $n$ values, the number of possible "partitions" $P(n)$ will follow the recurrence:
$$P(n)=P(n-1)+(n-1)\cdot P(n-2)$$
Since for the first subset in the partition, you can choose either it to contain only the first element (leaving $n-1$ elements that also have to be partitioned), or choose it to contain the first element, and another one of the other $n-1$ element (leaving $n-2$ elements for the recurrence).

Now, you can try to solve the recurrence and find a closed form if you like to.

Comment: @Yes, that is the meaning of my first comment. Also see [OEIS A000085](http://oeis.org/A000085).